# How to display CKEditor content in HTML page?

Tags: html, ckeditor, fckeditor

In my application I have used CKEditor text editor to store large data.

That data may come from another html page by copying content from any web page.

When doing above scenario,

if client missed any to copy properly ended html tags from that web page, they copied incomplete html content. When client paste it inside CKEditor, it showing good.

But If I display whole content without CKEditor,

Its leading to following issues,

1. Page collapse , because if client copied partical (in completed content from other web page)
2. CSS class override

Please give solution for that.

Comment: The solution is to use a strict ruleset for Advanced Content Filter. Beyond that; please provide use with an example of what "Page collapse" and "CSS class override" means. Show us something like "CKEditor produces `<p color="red">DERP<p>HERP</p>" but I want it to  produce `<p>DERP</p><p>HERP</p>". It's very unclear what the actual problem is in your question.